# Selecting only those objects that have N apartments in radius of K meters using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, query

Example:

- we have three commercial property objects (red ones, point geometry)
- we have many residential houses (blue ones, point geometry) with many apartments

Task:

Select only those objects (red ones) that have more than N apartments within  radius of K meters. In one query.

Is this possible?

[image: picture]

Picture for clarity:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible. Something like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM commercial AS c
JOIN houses AS h
  ON ST_DWithin( c.geom, h.geom, k_radius )
GROUP BY c.geom
HAVING count(h.geom) > N
```

Comment: Not count of houses. Sum of apartments of houses in K radius must be greater than some N value.

Comment: @EgorIvanov I'm not even sure what you're talking about, I had to do a lot of reading into the question to try to answer it. Perhaps you could be more clear about the difference between apartments and houses.

Comment: Each house has many apartments.

Comment: Show test data DML/DDL with WKT or `ST_MakePoint`... and a desired result.

Comment: Note that number of houses could be more than 10000.

Comment: Added picture for clarity.

Comment: That's not data, I still see only houses -- which my answer addresses. I have no idea what an apartment is in the real world, or how it's marked up in your database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69275/discussion-between-egor-ivanov-and-evan-carroll).